# How do you decide which level a function should be at in python?

Tags: python

I have a file called file_parsers.py and it contains the following class:

```
class FileParser():

    def __init__(self, file_text):
        self.file_text = file_text

    def do_something(self):
        my_value = func_with_no_state()
```

I'm not sure what questions to ask when deciding whether func_with_no_state() should be inside the class or outside of the class as a file-level function?

Also, is it easier to stub this function when it is at a file-level or inside the class?

Comment: What do you mean with `func_with_no_state` and what does it do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do_something() and func_with_no_state() are very generic names. What do they do?

Comment: This is more of an OOP or design question. It's not specifically related to Python. A very rough answer would be If your function is related to class and/or uses variables that are shared across class methods then use a class. If your function works independently and doesn't use class variables then keep it outside.

Comment: @AmitTripathi the one caveat being that perhaps you might want a  function with no bound state, but you still want inheritance. Although, I've rarely found that to be necessary. Usually, I have a mix of class definitions and standalone functions in a module.

Comment: Yes, for methods that are not related to class but either for readability, inheritance, etc reason still need to be in class, We can use @staticmethod syntactical sugar :)

Comment: Sorry for the awful method names, I thought they would be helpful cause their functionality didn't matter, and my func_with_no_state() meant that it was a function without using any of the instance variables or inheritance (in other words, it could easily be a class function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... Does any other class use `func_with_no_state`? If not, it should be hidden within `FileParser`. If something else does use it, you have a bigger question. If `OtherClass` uses `func_with_no_state` pretty frequently (on par with `FileParser`) then it would be a good idea to keep `func_with_no_state` outside so that both classes can use it. But if `FileParser` is by far the main user, then `OtherClass` could just pull the function from `FileParser`'s definition.